# Fail SonarQube quality gate when coverage decreases

Tags: code-coverage, sonarqube

I'm using SonarQube 4.3 and try to get a quality gate (formerly known as alerts) working which fails when the integration tests coverage has decreased since last analysis.

Does anyone know how to get to this?

Comment: Have you tried the steps here - http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Gates ?

Comment: yes I did, but it's not explained how to set the thresholds. I tried various things like 
"Coverage Delta since last analysis less than 100"
"Coverage Delta since last analysis less than 0"
...
but nothing shows the desired effect.
It seems to me the number I enter is always treated as an absolute value and refers to the current coverage.

Comment: Hmmm...we're still using Alerts and for that we have "Coverage Delta since last analysis is less than 0%" which works, so it sounds like what you're doing *should* work.

Comment: In Alerts the UI has a '%' sign next to the input-box you put the figure into, so you don't have to actually put the '%' sign in, just the figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, that's it. Set "Coverage, Delta since last analysis, less than, 0". The "0" goes in the error field, if this should cause an error.
Thanks Disco 3

Comment: Apparently this feature is no longer available in SonarQube 5.6.6. Quality Gates only support absolute measures and changes within the "Leak period". Or am I just too stupid to find the "Delta since last analysis" option?