# How to fail quality qate in SonarQube when number of issues increased since last successful analysis

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I'm using SonarQube 4.2.1 for analyzing maven projects and I'd like to fail the quality gate when the number of issues is higher than the last *successful* analysis (QG was green).

I'm aware of [Fail SonarQube quality gate when coverage decreases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23673245/fail-sonarqube-quality-gate-when-coverage-decreases) but it does not cover all my needs, because the QG would be green also, when build #1 has 5 issues (with QG green), build #2 8 issues and build #3 has 7 issues, which is less than the last analysis but still more than last successful build #1.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add the following condition:

- Metric: "New issues"
- Delta since previous analysis
- "Is greater than"
- "0" in error

Comment: Well, this does not work. When I configure a QG like this and run three builds like that:<br>
#1 1 issue -> green<br>
#2 3 issues -> red<br>
#3 2 issues -> green<br>
<br>
This is not my goal, the QG should be green after having 1 or less issues again.